# Sum Function brings up box to input value

Tags: ms-access

Working with Access SQL queries and when I enter a sum function instead of returning the sum of the values it brings up a box asking me to input a number. The entire code is trying to return the transactions that contain more than five products.

```
SELECT SoldVia.TID, sum(SoldVia.NoOfItems) as "TotalSold"

From SalesTransaction INNER JOIN SoldVia ON SalesTransaction.TID = SoldVia.TID

Group By SoldVia.ProductID, SoldVia.TID

Having TotalSold>5;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the Having statement to the following:

Having Sum(SoldVia.NoOfItems)>5

At the moment Access is treating the TotalSold as an implicit parameter which is why it is asking for a value when the query is run.